# Function is not executing

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I am new to Python so I am facing bit problem in the code. I have some functions but `tota_additional_bonus()` and `tota_bonus()` are not working because they do not show the `print` values.

```
import sys
def compute(sale,persent):      #function to compute bonus
    return(sale*persent/100)
while (1):
    try:
        print ("Enter Sales Price For Toyata $")
        toyota=int(input())
        print ("Enter Sales Price For Nissan $")
        nissan=int(input())
        print ("Enter Sales Price For Ford $")
        ford=int(input())

        print ("Enter Number Of Sales For Toyata in 2014")
        to=int(input())
        print ("Enter Number of Sales For Nissan in 2014")
        ni=int(input())
        print ("Enter Number Of Sales For Ford in 2014")
        fo=int(input())



    except ValueError:
        print ("Enter An Integer")
        sys.exit()

    sales= ((toyota*to)+(nissan*ni)+(ford*fo))         #calculating total sales of abc



    ct=(toyota*to)             # total sells toyata
    cn=(nissan*ni)             # total sells nissan
    cf=(ford*fo)               # total sells toyata

    print ("Contribution Of Toyota $",ct,"in Total Sales")
    print ("Contribution Of Nissan $",cn,"in Total Sales")
    print ("Contribution Of Ford $",cf,"in Total Sales")
    print ("Total Sales for ABC",sales)

    if sales <= 500000:
        bonus=compute(sales,0.1)

    elif sales >=500001 and sales <=1000000:
        bonus=compute(sales,0.2)+500

    elif sales >=1000001 and sales <=5000000:
        bonus=compute(sales,0.3)+1500

    elif sales >=500001 and sales <=10000000:
        bonus=compute(sales,0.4)+13500
    elif sales >10000000:
        bonus=compute(sales,0.5)+33500

    print ("Total Bonus\n",bonus)       #total bonus

    cty=(ct*bonus)/sales             #bonus contribution toyata
    cny=(cn*bonus)/sales             #bonus contribution nissan
    cfy=(cf*bonus)/sales             #bonus contribution toyata

    print ("Contribution Of Toyota $",cty,"in Total Bonus")
    print ("Contribution Of Nissan $",cny,"in Total Bonus")
    print ("Contribution Of Ford $",cfy,"in Total Bonus")


    print ("Input the Additional bonus for toyota in %")
    x=int(input())
    print ("Input the Additional bonus for Nissan in %")
    y=int(input())
    print ("Input the Additional bonus for Ford in %")
    z=int(input())


    def additionalbonus(bonus,extra):       #function to calculate additional bonus
        return (bonus*extra)
    xn= additionalbonus(bonus,x)
    yn= additionalbonus(bonus,y)
    zn= additionalbonus(bonus,z)


    print("Additional Bonus for toyota",xn)
    print("Additional Bonus for nissan",yn)
    print("Additional Bonus for ford",zn)


    def tota_additional_bonus(xn,yn,zn):       #calculating total additional bonus 
        t_n = xn +yn + zn
        print ("Total Adiitional Bonus is",t_n)

    def tota_bonus(bonus,t_n):                 #calculating total bonus distributed by ABC
        bonus_n=bonus+t_n
        print ("Total Bonus distributed is",bonus_n)

    print ("Enter Y to Calculate for another Year or N to Exit")
    var= input()

    if var == 'y':
        pass
    elif var == 'n':
        exit()


input()
```

Comment: That's a lot of code.  Can you strip it down to a minimal example?

Comment: Also, please review the indentation - it's important in Python. If that's now your code is really laid out, no wonder you're having trouble.

Comment: its working in my computer but   i dont understand y two funcntions are not executing

Comment: What do you mean it's working? If the functions aren't executing, what *is* happening? And does the code in the question look exactly like it does in your IDE?

Comment: i got three functions first one executes and shows out put but not second and third that is the problem

Comment: def additionalbonus(bonus,extra):       
        return (bonus*extra)
    xn= additionalbonus(bonus,x)
    yn= additionalbonus(bonus,y)
    zn= additionalbonus(bonus,z)
   

    print("Additional Bonus for toyota",xn)
    print("Additional Bonus for nissan",yn)
    print("Additional Bonus for ford",zn)
   

    def tota_additional_bonus(xn,yn,zn):       #calculating total additional bonus 
        t_n = xn +yn + zn
        print ("Total Adiitional Bonus is",t_n)
    def tota_bonus(bonus,t_n):                
        bonus_n=bonus+t_n
        print ("Total Bonus distributed is",bonus_n)

Comment: while running it does not show any errors but it does not print out put from last two fucntions

Comment: @user3600866 Well, you're defining the functions, but never actually _calling_ them. If you just want the code inside them to execute, don't put the lines in a method. If you want the code in methods, you need to _call_ the methods after defining them.

Comment: yes exactly thats the problem i need to print the values from both functions

Comment: but still its not printing anything

Comment: @user3600866 I strongly recommend that you take this code over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com once you have it working.

Comment: @user3600866 *"still its [sic] not printing anything"*. What do you mean "still"? What change have you made? Edit your question and (again) **please review the code formatting**.

Comment: @user3600866 To call the first one, add an actual call to the function, the line `tota_additional_bonus(xn,yn,zn)` after defining the function. I'll leave calling the second one as an exercise.

Comment: @user3600866 It's a bit like the function `print`, the framework defines it (as you do in the code with your functions) but just because it's defined, it does not print everything, it waits for a `print('hello')` to actually call the function and print something.

Comment: nothing printing for those print functions

Comment: @user3600866 well could you edit the question to show us how your code looks now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here at the end of your main `while` loop:

```
print("Additional Bonus for ford",zn)


def tota_additional_bonus(xn,yn,zn):       #calculating total additional bonus 
    t_n = xn +yn + zn
    print ("Total Adiitional Bonus is",t_n)

def tota_bonus(bonus,t_n):                 #calculating total bonus distributed by ABC
    bonus_n=bonus+t_n
    print ("Total Bonus distributed is",bonus_n)

print ("Enter Y to Calculate for another Year or N to Exit")
```

You *define* two functions that `print` the sums of their arguments, but *never actually call them*.  Also, it appears that the second function needs a value that is calculated in the first one but not returned.

Instead, try:

```
print("Additional Bonus for ford",zn)


def tota_additional_bonus(xn,yn,zn): # define function 
    t_n = xn +yn + zn
    print ("Total Adiitional Bonus is",t_n)
    return t_n # return result

t_n = tota_additional_bonus(xn, yn, zn) # call function and assign result

def tota_bonus(bonus,t_n): # define function 
    bonus_n=bonus+t_n
    print ("Total Bonus distributed is",bonus_n)

tota_bonus(bonus, t_n) # call function 

print ("Enter Y to Calculate for another Year or N to Exit")
```

Comment: No problem. There are still a lot of issues in your code, so I would still recommend a code review. You should edit your question there to give the complete, working code, correctly formatted, and add information about what you're trying to do; the community is not receptive of code dumps without introduction. Try reading their help center and a few existing questions to get a feel for the site.